# Confirm delete with laravel form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, confirm

Problem with confirm delete, all works fine, but if you click cancel in confirm popup it will delete the item from DB. Any ideas? Please show with code example, I'm new to laravel.

```
<script>

  function ConfirmDelete()
  {
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  }

</script>

{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['path_delete_time', $time->id], 'onsubmit' => 'ConfirmDelete()']) !!}

  {!! Form::hidden('case_id', $project->id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

  {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'specialButton')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add return to your `onsubmit` call. so the value the function returns determines if the form gets submitted or not.

```
'onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDelete()'
```

Comment: great thanks, for links it was easy via Laravel's 'data-confirm' but this had be stumped.

Answer (score 6):

Simple put jQuery code for prompt box when submit form or delete record.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('.deleteGroup').on('submit',function(e){
        if(!confirm('Do you want to delete this item?')){
              e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".specialButton").click(function(){
            return confirm("Do you want to delete this ?");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the form an id, and use jQuery:

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['path_delete_time', $time->id], 'id' => 'FormDeleteTime']) !!}

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#FormDeleteTime").submit(function (event) {
                 var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                    if (x) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {

                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

without any function calls ...

```
'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("are you sure ?")'
```

example

```
            {!! Form::open(['url'=>'posts/'.$post->id.'/delete','method'=>'DELETE','class'=>'form-horizontal',
        'role'=>'form','onsubmit' => 'return confirm("are you sure ?")'])!!}
```

using laravel 5

Answer (score 2):

In my new project (Laravel 5.3) I'm using the following:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin.user.delete', $user], 'onsubmit' => 'return confirmDelete()']) !!}
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Mention the **'onsubmit' => 'return confirmDelete()'** otherwise I had some problems when I close the alert without confirming the question.

JavaScript:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
}
```

Comment: Just return `result`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is happening right now is that you get a popup which delays the redirect to the deletion page.

What you might do is only generate a link which on its turn generates a form in js. [Like what they're doing here (only with JQuery)](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/delete-links-with-confirmation-box-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would generalise this out a bit:

.html

```
<form method="post" action="..." class="has-confirm" data-message="Delete this Thing?">...</form>
```

.js

```
$("form.has-confirm").submit(function (e) {
  var $message = $(this).data('message');
  if(!confirm($message)){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but this is the smoothest way IMO:

```
'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Do you want to delete this user?");'
```

in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way in laravel blade confirmation show.

```
<form action="{{route('users.destroy',$item->id)}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" onclick ="return confirm('Do you want to delete this user?')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-icon-split">
        <span class="icon text-white-50">
            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </span>
    </button>
</form>
```